# Generating an HTML list of descendants with Python

Tags: qgis, python, attribute-table, html

I'm currently working on a GIS project for the alternate history novel. As my point of divergence is sometime around 10 BCE, the languages are different so I am editing an ISO code table to account for this.

I'd like to be able to create a tree for each language to keep track of how languages evolved.

I currently have this as a QGIS expression:

```
'<ul style="list-style-type:none;">'+if(type='Language Group',ISO_639_2,ISO_639_3)+' - <b>'+NAME+'</b>'+
array_to_string(
    array_foreach(
        array_foreach(
            array_foreach(
                children,
                grabChildren(get_feature(@layer,'NAME',@element))),
                    array_to_string(array(' ',attributes(get_feature(@layer,'NAME',@element['langName']))[if(attributes(get_feature(@layer,'NAME',@element['langName']))['TYPE']='Language Group','ISO_639_2','ISO_639_3')],' - <b>',attributes(get_feature(@layer,'NAME',@element['langName']))['NAME'],'</b>'),' ')
            ),
    '<li>'+@element+'</li>'),
'')
+'</ul>'
```

So for Indo-European languages I currently get this:

INE - **Indo-European languages**

gem  -  **Germanic languages**

inc  -  **Indic languages**

roa  -  **Romance languages**

I can only get the *immediate* children with this method, I'm sure that in Python I can do this recursively - such that it will display the grandchildren, great grandchildren, and so on - but I'm not sure how. Does anyone know how I would go about this?

Here's my attempt to build that function. Each child should be nested within the parent dictionary.

```py
from qgis.core import QgsProject

def langName(feature):
    thisLang = feature['NAME']
    return thisLang

def langCode(feature):
    thisType = feature['TYPE']
    thisCodeA = feature['ISO_639_3']
    thisCodeB = feature['ISO_639_2']
    thisCodeC = feature['ISO_639_1']
    if thisType is 'Language Group':
        return thisCodeB
    else:
        return thisCodeA

def grabLayer(string):
    layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName(string)[0]
    return layer

def grabFeatures(field,value,string)
    layer = grabLayer(string)
    expressionParts = [field,value]
    expression = '='.join(expressionParts) 
    try:
        thisChildren = layer.selectByExpression(expression, QgsVectorLayer.SetSelection)
        return thisChildren
    except:
        pass

def grabParent(feature):
    try:
        thisParent = feature['PARENT']
        return thisParent
    except:
        pass

def langTemplate(langID,lang,layer,children={}):
    thisLayer = layer
    eLangID = langID
    eLang = lang
    eChildren = grabFeatures('"PARENT"',eLang,thisLayer)
    entry = {
        "langID": eLangID,
        "langName": eLang
    }
    if len(eChildren)>0:
        childEntries = {}
        for c in eChildren:
            cLangID = langID(c)
            cLang = langName(c)
            cEntry = langTemplate(cLangID,cLang,thisLayer)
            newChild = {
                cLang = cEntry
            }
            childEntries.update(newChild)
        entry.update({"children": childEntries})
    else:
        pass
    return entry


@qgsfunction(args='auto', group='Custom', referenced_columns=[])
def grabChildren(feature,layer):
    currParent = feature
    currLayer = grabLayer(layer)
    currLang =  langName(currParent)
    currID = langCode(currParent)
    mainDict = {}
    masterDict = langTemplate(currID,currLang,currLayer)
    return masterDict
```

Comment: It’s not clear whether you’re trying to do this using PyQGIS or pure Python. Either way please include a code attempt.

Comment: Is this mainly about html? Where to ask about that?